# PreferenceManager widget app android killed

Tags: android, widget, lockscreen

I am trying to transfer some data between a lock screen widget and a parent app for an Android device. I am doing this via SharedPreferences (PreferenceManager)

```
SharedPreferences getPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());
```

The problem is that when the parent app is killed (task manager), the context.getApplicationContext() value changes and the shared preferences can no longer be fetched.

Is there a solution for this?